# Variable not set after simple statement

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, three.js

I am creating a front-end app with vue.js (using vue-cli to test it) in Firefox. I also use three.js.

Sometimes (around 20% of the time) one of my variable is not modified by a simple a = a + b statement where b is not equal to 0.

If I pause my code and manually change the a variable to any value via the debugger then it works.

I checked with console.log (bellow), Firefox debugger, VSCode debugger (using firefox). I am going to try with chromium as soon as possible.

This part of the code is not directly related to vue.js or three.js, it lives independently in my class. None of those variables are modified outside the code.

```
if (this._cardId === 3 && this.id === 58) {
    console.log("A: this._currentHeightUpdateTimer", this._currentHeightUpdateTimer, "delta", delta)
    console.log("this._currentHeightUpdateTimer = this._currentHeightUpdateTimer + delta")
}
this._currentHeightUpdateTimer = this._currentHeightUpdateTimer + delta
if (this._cardId === 3 && this.id === 58) {
    console.log("B: this._currentHeightUpdateTimer", this._currentHeightUpdateTimer, "delta", delta)
}
```

---

```
A: this._currentHeightUpdateTimer 0 delta 33035
this._currentHeightUpdateTimer = this._currentHeightUpdateTimer + delta
B: this._currentHeightUpdateTimer 0 delta 33035
```

I am looking for advices, or directions to look at.

Edit: [the entire class file](https://hastebin.com/ipupimamej.js).

Edit2: This is the loop from three.js calling the method:

```
_update() {
    const delta = this._getDelta()
    this.cortex.update(delta, this.scene.container) // here
    this.mouse.update()
    this.scene.render()
    requestAnimationFrame(this._update.bind(this))
}
```

Comment: Obvious suspicion would fall on chronology. How are you ensuring that the order of processes is what it should be? It sounds currently like the variable's assignment is affected by unpredictable load order (e.g. of external scripts, modules etc).

Comment: Is `_currentHeightUpdateTimer` a getter or a computed property?

Comment: @adiga No, it's not and it's not accessed in any other object.

Comment: @Utkanos I set the variable to 0 in the constructor and reset it to 0 after this code on some condition. I tried to remove the reset call but the issue was still the same.

Comment: @Utkanos I added a link to the class file in my post.

Comment: Any chance you could create a sandbox in which we could recreate the problem?

Comment: @JoaoPereira I'm sorry, really don't see how. I am not allowed by law to give the entire code and I could not isolate this part easily. I understand how hard it is to help me from so little information.

Comment: Then I can't really see how to help, description is vague and the code you provided doesn't seem to reflect the cause of the problem.

Comment: I understand. I am fairly new to javascript, any insight on how to study the issue would be of great help.

Comment: Have you tried saving it to a new property? Or logging the value of `this`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189409/discussion-between-joao-pereira-and-jean).